# How can i make user to choose whether want to continue using the program or not? if user not using,will display "Thankyou for using"?

Tags: loops, assembly, x86-16

```
.MODEL SMALL
.STACK 100
.DATA

    prompt1 DB 10,15,'ENTER ANY WORDS : $'
    prompt2 DB 10,15,'LENGTH OF THE WORDS IS : $'
    prompt3 DB 10,15,'REVERSE OF YOUR ENTERED WORDS IS : $'     
    PROMPT DB "Do you want to continue using(y/n)?$"
    ERROR DB "Please enter y or n only.$"
    INPUT DB ?
    NEWLINE DB 0AH,0DH,"$"
    EXIT DB 'Thankyou for using ! Please come back next time!'

    P LABEL BYTE
    M1 DB 0FFH
    L1 DB ?
    P3 DB 0FFH DUP ('$')
    P4 DB 0FFH DUP ('$')

DISPLAY MACRO MSG
    MOV AH,9
    LEA DX,MSG
    INT 21H
ENDM   

.CODE
MAIN PROC
        MOV AX,@DATA
        MOV DS,AX                

        DISPLAY prompt1

        LEA DX,P
        MOV AH,0AH    
        INT 21H

        DISPLAY prompt2

        MOV DL,L1
        ADD DL,30H
        MOV AH,2
        INT 21H

        DISPLAY prompt3

        LEA SI,P3
        LEA DI,P4

        MOV DL,L1
        DEC DL
        MOV DH,0
        ADD SI,DX
        MOV CL,L1
        MOV CH,0

;----- Reverse the strings
REVERSE:
        MOV AL,[SI]
        MOV [DI],AL
        INC DI
        DEC SI
        LOOP REVERSE

        DISPLAY P4

        LEA SI,P3
        LEA DI,P4   

        MOV CL,L1
        MOV CH,0

        MOV AH,4CH
        INT 21H



REPEAT:

        MOV AH,09H
        LEA DX,NEWLINE
        INT 21H

        MOV AH,09H
        LEA DX,PROMPT
        INT 21H

        ;-------------GET USER INPUT
        MOV AH,01H
        INT 21H
        MOV INPUT,AL

        CMP AL,"y"
        JZ DISPLAY1
        CMP AL,"n"
        JE TERMINATE
        JNE ERRORMSG
DISPLAY1:
        MOV AH,09H
        LEA DX,NEWLINE
        INT 21H

        ADD prompt1,1
        MOV AH,02H
        MOV DL,prompt1
        INT 21H
        JMP REPEAT

ERRORMSG:
        MOV AH,09H
        LEA DX,ERROR
        INT 21H
        JMP REPEAT

        TERMINATE:
        MOV AH,4CH
        LEA DX,EXIT
        INT 21H

MAIN ENDP
END MAIN
```

Comment: any solutions? please i need help

Answer (score 0):

The issue that your question is about is easily solved.

> ```
> TERMINATE:
>     MOV AH,4CH
>     LEA DX,EXIT
>     INT 21H
> ```

The above snippet tries to do 2 things at once. Displaying a closing message AND terminating the program. You need to use 2 distinct DOS calls here:

```
TERMINATE:
    lea dx, EXIT
    mov ah, 09h    ; DOS.PrintString
    int 21h
    mov ax, 4C00h  ; DOS.Terminate
    int 21h
```

The below message needs the $-terminator to be acceptable for DOS.

> ```
> EXIT DB 'Thankyou for using ! Please come back next time!'
> ```

---

> ```
> prompt1 DB 10,15,'ENTER ANY WORDS : $'
> prompt2 DB 10,15,'LENGTH OF THE WORDS IS : $'
> prompt3 DB 10,15,'REVERSE OF YOUR ENTERED WORDS IS : $'
> ```

Shouldn't these numbers 15 become 13, the ASCII code for carriage return?

Comment: Also should be mentioned that your method of displaying LENGTH OF THE WORDS by adding 30H to the contents of L1 only works for numbers not greater than 9. Otherwise you'll need to divide L1 by 10 and use the remainder.